# c code is unable to compile when run on vscode with github and cs50

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

hello I am currently working through cs50. my code passes all the checks, but it fails to compile when I check it. Here's the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int width = get_int("input the desired width, between 1 and 8: ");

    while (width < 1 || width > 8)
    {
        int width = get_int("input the desired width, between 1 and 8: ");
    }

    for (int i = 0, i < width, i++)
    {
        for (int j = width - i - 2; j >= 0, j--)
        {
            printf("");
        }

        for (int row = 0; row <= width; row ++);
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: You say it fails to compile - but how do you know that? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: yes, but was messing up when i tried to post: 
                 error: redefinition of 'i'
for (int i = 0, i < width, i++)
^
mario.c:13:14: note: previous definition is here
for (int i = 0, i < width, i++)
^
mario.c:13:23: error: expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier
for (int i = 0, i < width, i++)
^
mario.c:13:23: error: expected expression
mario.c:15:39: warning: relational comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
for (int j = width - i - 2; j >= 0, j--)
~~^~~~
mario.c:15:48: error: expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier
for (int j = width - i - 2; j >= 0, j--)
^

Comment: `for (int i = 0, i < width, i++)` should have semicolons, not commas.

Comment: If you (a) properly indent, and (b) read your warnings/errors, the problem will become obvious quickly : [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/38PY4nPaK). The cs50 program is by-in-large crap, but these kinds of problems are still included in their curriculum. Don't try to skip ahead.

Comment: You've got commas in places where you should have semicolons.  Also, what's that `while` loop supposed to do (why does it declare a new `width` variable in the body)?  If you want to set a new value for `width` when it's value is out of range, make it not const but don't redeclare it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```c
const int width = ...;
...
int width = ...;
```

- width must not be const if you want to change it later
- if you want to reassign variable's value you don't prepend it with type specifier

```c
for (int i = 0, i < width, i++)
{
    for (int j = width - i - 2; j >= 0, j--)
    {
    ...
```

parts of for loop (initialization, condition and advancement) are delimited by semicolon, not comma

```c
for (int row = 0; row <= width; row ++);
{
    printf("#");
}
```

you must not put semicolon between for's "head" and "body"